# how can i skip two dollar signs in row from refering to process id in awk?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

i'm trying to read from a file "file", with a for loop before the awk, so the "$j" would refer to the j variable in the loop, now i'm trying to get the first field on that file using awk, so i tried using $$j, but it gets translated into process id because of the two dollar signs in row, how can i avoid this?

this is the code

```
for ((j = 1; j < $number_of_insertion_col; j++)); do
    var=$(awk -F"\t:\t" 'NR==1 {print "'$$j'" }' file)
done
```

sample input

```
"col1(pk)   :   col2    :   col3    :   "
```

my desired output is "col1(pk) in the firs iteration, then col2 in the second and so on and so forth

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment

Comment: @Cyrus added those, thanks

Comment: This question is not about using shell variables. It's about NOT using shell variables.

Comment: It's **extremely** unlikely that calling awk in a shell loop is the right approach for whatever it is you're trying to do. If you ask a new question about how to do whatever it is we can help you do whatever that is the right way (as opposed to helping you implement the wrong way).

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the value to a variable using `-v` instead of directly injecting it to the code:

```
for (( j = 1; j < number_of_insertion_col; ++j )); do
    var=$(awk -F"\t:\t" -v j="$j" 'NR == 1 { print $j }' file)
done
```

This answers your question but you can provide more details so people can suggest how you might be able to accomplish your goal better.

Comment: thanks a lot, this worked